# Intercept incoming calls (not answering state) in iOS

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I'm trying to find out how can I intercept when a phone call received and no one answer and then it goes to voice mail.
I looked into CTCall and CTCallCenter but I'm not sure whether they are not answer for my problems or it's not allowed for apps to AppStore.
Ideas/thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but there is NO public API by Apple to intercept the call of the Phone application without jailbreak! 
And it wont be able to see App store if you are going to use Private methods

**If your application is active when a call event takes place, the system dispatches the event to your handler immediately. However, call events can also take place while your application is suspended. While it is suspended, your application does not receive call events.**

Comment: So: CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    [callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", call.callID, call.callState);
    }]; won't work?

Comment: OK, anyway to intercept calls without jailbreaking when app is suspended (i.e. in background)?

Comment: Nope, its not possible :(