# Is it possible to have an iPhone app that replaces the default call manager with interface to receive and send calls

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6

This might be obvious but is it possible to have an iPhone app that replaces the default call manager. I would like it to listen register with the low-level services to receive and make calls. I am not sure if apple exposes this libraries to apps. At minimum I would like the app to be able to receive.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Apple doesn't allow this. You might be able to accomplish this through a jailbroken device but there would be no documentation to assist you and you would need to discover private APIs.

As noted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375880/557358)

> If your application is active when a call event takes place, the
>   system dispatches the event to your handler immediately. However, call
>   events can also take place while your application is suspended. While
>   it is suspended, your application does not receive call events.

Comment: So it isn't possible for an app to intercept a call. How about making a call from an App?

Comment: You can open a "tel:" URL, but it will display the standard "Call?" pop-up box. See this question for some examples: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html As a broader point, in general you cannot replace any system feature of an iPhone. Apps are apps. They (in general) cannot modify how the iPhone behaves.

Comment: Appears it is possible make call from within app please see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732043/make-calls-from-iphone-app/9732924#9732924. Is this what I should be looking for?

Comment: Yes, that referenced answered is just using the standard "tel:" URL method. Doing so move your app into the background and bring the native phone app to the foreground to initiate the call.